# A conjecture/algorithm about prime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

I am not a mathematician, but I used to love reading Euclid's elements. In 2013 I discovered a very inefficient way of generating prime numbers exactly using a statement I deduced while reading BOOK VII:

If a set of $n$ prime numbers, $p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_n$, contains a complete continuum of primes such that $p_g$ marks the (inclusive) upper bound of this continuum and all primes below $p_g$ are present in the set, then all numbers of the form 
\begin{gather*} 
\left|\prod_{i=1}^m \,\,\,p_i^{s_j} \pm \prod_{i=m+1}^n p_i^{s_k}\right|
\end{gather*}
that are less than ${p_{g}}^2$ and greater than the unit are also prime, where $m$ is less than $n$ ($n \geq 2$) and $s_j$ and $s_k$ denote any natural number.

I have written about it here, where you can also find few programs in Kotlin which demonstrate this up to a certain point (very inefficiently):
https://github.com/EtherBit/On-Immeasurable-Magnitudes

Is this known? Could somebody point me to more helpful resources.

Pardon the terminology and verbosity.

Comment: It's pretty easy to see that your number can't be divisible by any of your primes, so if it's less than the square of your largest prime (and isn't $1$) then it must be prime. You can probably learn more Number Theory from an intro Number Theory text, say, Niven, Zuckerman, and Montgomery, than you can from Euclid. Congrats on finding this by yourself, that's the main thing.

Comment: You might be interested in Guy, Lacampagne, and Selfridge, Primes at a Glance, Mathematics of Computation, Volume 48, Number 177, January 1987, pages 183-202, available at https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1987-48-177/S0025-5718-1987-0866108-3/S0025-5718-1987-0866108-3.pdf

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks for the link! Briefly skimmed through it. Seems to be similar.